A 2D circle (cake) is cut randomly with straight lines n-times. What's the expected number of pieces?
This is a Jane Street puzzle, and I will provide my working so far: 
I defined my 'random' cut as two numbers randomly selected from the range 0-2π mapped to the circumference of the circle, with a chord drawn between them. 
Furthermore, every point on the lines is either not an intersection, or the intersection of exactly two lines, as the probability of three random lines perfectly intersecting is 0. 
The circle starts as one piece, and for every cut, at least one new piece is added, as well as an additional new piece for each intersection the cut has with other lines. So the total formula for pieces would be: n+i+1, for n cuts and i intersections. 
From here, I need to calculate i in terms of n. For two random cuts, AB cutting from point A on the circumference to point B, and CD cutting from point C to point D, if neither AB nor CD are adjacent on the circumference, then there will be an intersection. 
After writing up the possible arrangements of {A,B,C,D}, I found that this is satisfied 1/3 of the time, so there is a 1/3 chance that any two given lines will intersect.
I feel that I am pretty close to a solution here, I just need to extend to probability that any two lines intersect to all n total lines. Unfortunately, I don't think the probabilities that a third line intersects either of the previous two are independant, so I think extending the previous argument I made with the set of 2n points to higher values than n=2 is the best path forward, but I am unsure how to do that. 
Thanks
